# Can non-global variables be modified inside a function in R?

Tags: r

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the semantics and grammar of R.  It appears to me that local variables aren't able to be modified inside of a function.

As an example, in this basic code, I would expect the `heatmap.matrix` variable to get updated when I call the `foo()` function.

```
heatmap.matrix <- matrix(rep(0,40000), nrow=200, ncol=200)

# foo function should just update a single cell of the declared matrix
foo <- function() { heatmap.matrix[40,40] <- 100}

heatmap.matrix[40,40]
[1] 0
foo()
heatmap.matrix[40,40]
[1] 0
# there I expected it to return 100.  Yet if I do it out of the function:
heatmap.matrix[40,40] <- 100
[1] 100
```

This leads me to believe that the **scope of variables isn't passed back after the function evaluates**.  **Is that the case with R?**  Is something else going on?  I feel like I really don't have a hang on what's going on.  Any help/insight would really be appreciated!

To give a quick explanation, in my code, I have a frequency table with `x` and `y` columns, and I'm trying to convert that into a 2-D matrix with the value corresponding to entry in the frequency table, or zero if there is no corresponding entry.  However, I'm unable to modify my matrix within an apply function.

Comment: the double-assignment operator `<<-` is used to modify variables outside of functions. Also, read up on [functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) and lexical scoping

Comment: `foo()` takes a copy of `heatmap.matrix`, and modifies it inside the function. The global `heatmap.matrix` is never modified. Often, R takes a copy of an object, makes an alteration, and then returns the whole object, like `foo <- function() { heatmap.matrix[40,40] <- 100; heatmap.matrix}`

Comment: You can assign outside of the local environment with `<<-`, but it's generally bad form. It's better to return the altered object, so it's clear from the code that you're reassigning the variable, and nothing gets invisibly altered. `<<-` is also somewhat dangerous, as depending on your structure and variable names (and those in other parent environments), it may not assign where you intend, which could introduce bugs for you, or worse, somebody you gave the function to who doesn't have the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to update a global variable, in a function using `get` and `assign` function. Below is the code, which does the same :

```
heatmap.matrix <- matrix(rep(0,40000), nrow=200, ncol=200)

# foo function should just update a single cell of the declared matrix
varName <- "heatmap.matrix" 
foo <- function() { 
  heatmap.matrix.copy <- get(varName)
  heatmap.matrix.copy[40,40] <- 100
  assign(varName, heatmap.matrix.copy, pos=1)
}

heatmap.matrix[40,40]
#[1] 0
foo()
heatmap.matrix[40,40]
# [1] 100
```

you should read up a bit on environments concept. The best place to start is http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Thanks, I think this and the comments above answer what I was asking.  I guess R is like Lisp where it returns new copies of everything.